# Loop through data and color rows with requests that contain one name only

Tags: vba, loops, for-loop

I am trying to write a piece of code, that will color all requests which contain only one unique name for each request.

My code [UPDATED]

```
    Private Function NameInList(searchName As String, MyArray As Variant) As Boolean

MyArray = Range("B1:B50")
    Dim found As Boolean: found = False
    Dim name As Variant
    For Each name In MyArray
        If name = searchName Then
            found = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next name
    NameInList = found
End Function



Sub DeleteRows2()

Dim r As Long, LR As Long
Dim ReqNo As Long, CCFullName As Long
Dim rgn2 As Range

LR = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'Request Number
ReqNo = Application.Match("Request Number", Sheet1.Rows(1), 0)
'Client Contact Assignee: Full Name
CCFullName = Application.Match("Client Contact Assignee: Full Name", Sheet1.Rows(1), 0)

Set rgn2 = Columns(CCFullName)

'delete if CounIf = 1

For r = LR To 2 Step -1
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rgn2, Cells(r, CCFullName).Value) = 1 Or NameInList(Cells(r, CCFullName).Value) = True Then
    Rows(r).Interior.Color = rgbBlueViolet
'    Rows(r).Delete
    End If

Next r



End Sub
```

The code above only colors names that are unique for the whole document, which is Mary H, Anna W and Thomas Y.
However, I need the code to include also the 3 below names which occur once only in a particular request.

```
7208497 Kevin M
7208497 Julia K
8138382 Shahida B
```

My data:

```
Request Number  Client Contact Assignee: Full Name
4350257 Eleanor B
4350257 Eleanor B
4350257 Mary H
8620428 Kevin M
8620428 Kevin M
7208497 Michael W
7208497 Kevin M
7208497 Michael W
7208497 Julia K
7191212 Thomas Y
7191212 Shahida B
7191212 Shahida B
7191212 Shahida B
8138382 Julia K
8138382 Julia K
8138382 Shahida B
8138382 Julia K
8138382 Anna W
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a function that checks if the name matches the additional items you've mentioned and adding an OR condition to your for loop?

[New Function]

```
Private Function NameInList(searchName as String, ArrayOfNames as Variant) as Boolean
    Dim found As Boolean: found = False
    Dim name As Variant
    For Each name In ArrayOfNames
        If name = searchName Then
            found = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next name
    NameInList = found
End Function
```

And then in your original For Loop, just change this line `If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rgn2, Cells(r, CCFullName).Value) = 1` to the following:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rgn2, Cells(r, CCFullName).Value) = 1 Or If NameInList(Cells(r, CCFullName).Value) = True
```

Comment: The names that were not caught ("Kevin M", "Julia K", "Shahida B") are examples. These will be different each time.

Comment: Ah OK, where will those names be coming from? The function could be adapted to receive an array of names sent as a parameter.

Comment: The data in the sheet will be replaced by data from other file downloaded from the system. The data I provided is just a sample. In truth in contains about 500 entries.

Comment: That's fine, so you just need to get that data into a usable array first. If the other file you mentioned is a workbook, you can simply declare a variant - ```Dim MyArray as Variant``` - and set it to be the value of the required range for example: ```MyArray = Range("A1:A10").Value``` then you could send ```MyArray``` as a parameter to the ```NameInList``` function.

Comment: I've updated the original function to include the additionally required parameter

Comment: I did as you advised and I receive a compile error: "Argument not Optional" If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rgn2, Cells(r, CCFullName).Value) = 1 Or NameInList(Cells(r, CCFullName).Value)

Comment: Did you add the array into the Function Call? Could you post the code you now have please?

Comment: Thanks. So the ```NameInList``` Function requires two parameters, the name your searching for and an Array Of Names to search through. As mentioned before you can simply pass in a range such as ```Range("A1:A10")``` based on where the additional names are located.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. I'm new to VBA and have no experience with functions. :(

Comment: No worries, let's start with where the additional names are located. Are they on another spreadsheet and if so, is that spreadsheet usually open when you're working on the other spreadsheet?

Comment: I will pull out the report from the system every week. And replace the data in Sheet1 (see My Data). I will be working on one spreadsheet.  Both request numbers in column 1 and names in the second column (Client Contact Assignee: Full Name) will be different. And my aim is to delete rows containing names that occur only once in a given request.

Comment: Can anyone guide me im the right direction on how to deal with my problem?